# Shortcut to Toggle Sidebar Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

After navigation most of the cases when into coding Don't need the `sidebar` for a while.

I there any key shortcut or command for toggle side bar visibility.

I found one command for `toolbar visibility` in the key mapping, couldn't find for toggle `sidebar` or `sidebar visibility` .

Comment: This is not a term that Eclipse uses. What do you mean by 'sidebar'?

Comment: I mean the `package explorer` and `project explorer` view which shown in the left side  @greg-449

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to maximize the current editor or view you're in, hiding all other panels (views), use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. You can also double-click on the editor tab. Doing either a second time will restore the editor/view to previous position.

Comment: although it doesn't  work on the sidebar, but serve the purpose, which is maximizing the  editor and reverting back to the previous view by minimizing the sidebar and restoring. If there is no more specific way then this is the correct answer I guess. thanks for you time @E-Riz

Answer (score 0):

Click the minimize button at the top right of the Package/Project explorer view to minimize the view:
[image]

(minimize is the small bar second from the right).